# Use PHP require() on localhost with windows

Tags: php, syntax

Problem:
[image]
[image]

I want to use the `require()` command 
from scripte\sicherheit\verschluesselung.php
to scripte/reg_einlesen.php (1 folder above the one I m within)

But I dont know the right Syntax for a Windows system.
I tried these 2 options:

```
require('../reg_einlesen.php');
require('..\reg_einlesen.php);
```

Would anyone plz tell me the right Syntax. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The first option looks good.

If it doesn't work try with `require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../reg_einlesen.php)'`

Comment: You are missing a `'` in your second example. I'm not sure if that is just a typo, but if it's your code you must add a ending `'`.

Comment: Be aware that the `require`s you make are always relative to the script that's being run. That's most likely your `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

`require('../reg_einlesen.php');`

Will go back in a directory then fetch the `reg_einlesen.php` file. This is the correct syntax for a Windows system. The same will also work on a Mac. It is not platform dependent but rather just the universal syntax for moving through a folder structure.

If you are in the directory:

`scripte/sicherheit/verschluesselung.php`

and you want to access the file:

`scripte/reg_einlesen.php`

You can use:

`require('../reg_einlesen.php');`

If you want to go back two directories you can use:

`require('../../reg_einlesen.php');`

Comment: How does this differ from what he did?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on your system, you can use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR which will have the desired value, instead of hardcoding '/' or '\'.

Comment: on windows doesn't matter, you can use forward or backward slash, either will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Maxi, it worked instant^^!

Here the correct syntax for everybody:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../reg_einlesen.php');
```

Comment: If you want delete my answer if Maxi is making one and vote him up instead of me, he deserves this for his fast and professional help!
I would vote too.